# Touch screen keyboard issue with winforms app on windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, touchscreen, windows-10-desktop

While running windows forms app on touch-screen device in Tablet mode when the on-screen keyboard is dismissed corresponding area (where keyboard was shown) becomes black.
Also clicking on the black area minimizes the app.

Environment:

- .Net 4.5.2
- WinForms app
- Windows 10 1903 touch screen device
- Tablet mode

Keyboard open:

[image: keyboard-open]

Keyboard close:

[image: keyboard-close]

Comment: I guess you just have to invalidate (repaint) form after OSK (on-screen keyboard) is closed.

Comment: I'm using dynamic contents on the form, i can set events for the form only. How to  configure OSK events in such cases?